# Simulink error: "FixedStepDiscrete" solver cannot be used

Tags: matlab, simulink

please if some one knows something in simulink help me,i have following model

[image]

i configured parameters as

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

but when i am running very strange and  ubnormal error comes

[image]

**

> how can i fix it?please help me

**

Answer (score 1):

You have used at least one block which has a continous state, but your solver is configured to fixed step. Try "Variable-Step" "ode45". You can find the options on the first screenshot.

Comment: @datodatuashvili It should do. You need to give us more information. What error message do you get? Have you set the solver to variable-step? It may be that you need some rate transition blocks to convert from variable to fixed step in the model, for the blocks that are fixed-step.